# Adding new values to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have a DataFrame where I need to add a new piece of information to each row - this piece of information is deduced from data already in the Data Frame.

Specifically I have a date, I want to take the date and run off to a service and return the Day of the Week, and insert it into that row in a new column:

Current Structure:

```
|Date      | Action1 | Action 2 |
=================================
|2014-10-15| a       | b        |
=================================
|2014-11-05| c       | d        |
=================================
```

The Goal is to get to this state:

```
|Date      |DOW    | Action1 | Action 2 |
========================================
|2014-10-15|Monday |a        | b        |
========================================
|2014-11-05|Tuesday|c        | d        |
========================================
```

I have a function that can intake a date and return the DOW,

```
def DOW(date):
   .....does some stuff....
   return Day_of_week
```

but I don't know how to best iterate over the dates in the DataFrame and insert the function return.

In a standard Dictionary i would just do:

```
for each in df:
   each.update({'DOW':DOW(each['Date']))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to iterate at all. Just do

```
df['DOW'] = df['Date'].map(DOW)
```

This will invoke your `DOW()` function on each element of `Date` in your Dataframe, and then assign the results to a column called `DOW`.

Comment: This is perfect - but i have now encountered a datetime format problem -

TypeError: Can't convert 'datetime.date' object to str implicitly

I tried to quickly call df['Date'].to_string()

But no luck - any thoughts?

Comment: @tgunn Given a variable `d` of type `datetime.date`, you can call `d.strftime('%F')`. To use a scalar function in a vector setting, you could try `df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%F'))`.